# Cannot find namespace 'google' in angular 14

Tags: angular

@angular/google-maps version: `14.1.1`

I am using angular 14 and implement google map using @angular/google-maps but through error
`Cannot find namespace 'google'.`

Here is stackblitz link [click...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-egjqpr?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the doc

The Google Maps JavaScript declaration files (see source files on GitHub) can be installed using NPM from the [@types/google.maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript) package

**Try this:**

```
 npm i -D @types/google.maps
```

Comment: After installing google types can you please share package.json?

Comment: Here is stackblitz link : `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-egjqpr?file=src/app/app.component.ts`

Comment: Have you tried in your local environment. For some reason it's not working in stackblitz

Comment: Working CodeSandBox:https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-bird-5j755o?file=/src/app/app.component.html. One more think don't share google map key in public

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your package doesn't installed successfully. First try this:

```
npm install @angular/google-maps --force
```

After that hard reload your app. It will works

Comment: As per your answer i tried but its not working